# Unable To Display Events - Fullcalandar - SQL - Error Message

Tags: php, html, sql, json

I'm working on a calendar. I can display the calendar and add an event successfully but am unable to display events on on the monthly view.

HTML Code:

```
<head>
    <title>The Honourable Gays Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                dayClick: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                eventSources: {
                    url: 'http:localhost/phplogin/all_events.php',                
                    error: function() {
                        alert('There was an error while fetching')
                    }
                },
                displayEventTime: false,
                eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
                dayClick: function() {
                    window.location.href = "add_event.html";
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I run this code I get the error message "There was an error while fetching".

PHP Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$events = array();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, Start_Date, End_Date FROM events');
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($results as $row){
      $events[] = array(
      'id'   => $row["id"],
      'title'   => 'ND',
      'start'   => $row["Start_Date"],
      'end'   => $row["End_Date"]
      );
    }
echo json_encode($events);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its seems your URL format need to fix

```js
url: 'http:localhost/phplogin/all_events.php',
```

to

```js
url: 'http://localhost/phplogin/all_events.php',
```

Comment: Hi Agus, thanks for your comment. I have amended the code and im still receiving the error message.

Comment: what is return by http://localhost/phplogin/all_events.php in your browser

, is your http://localhost/phplogin/all_events.php return JSON needed for the calendar as described in their documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: Hi, yes that is what the PHP code that is shown above is meant to do.